# Efficient grouping into dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples:

```
[('Player1', 'A', 1, 100),
('Player1', 'B', 15, 100),
('Player2', 'A', 7, 100),
('Player2', 'B', 65, 100),
('Global Total', None, 88, 100)]
```

Which I wish to convert to a dict in the following format:

```
{
  'Player1': {
              'A': [1, 12.5],
              'B': [15, 18.75],
              'Total': [16, 18.18]
           },
  'Player2': {
              'A': [7, 87.5],
              'B': [65, 81.25],
              'Total': [72, 81.81]
           },
  'Global Total': {
            'A': [8, 100],
            'B': [80, 100]
         }
}
```

So each Player dict has it's *local* total value and it's percentage according to it's *global* total value.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
fixed_vals = {}
for name, status, qtd, prct in data_set: # This is the list of tuples var
  if name in fixed_vals:
    fixed_vals[name].update({status: [qtd, prct]})
  else:
    fixed_vals[name] = {status: [qtd, prct]}

fixed_vals['Global Total']['Total'] = fixed_vals['Global Total'].pop(None)
total_a = 0
for k, v in fixed_vals.items():
  if k != 'Global Total':
    total_a += v['A'][0]

fixed_vals['Global Total']['A'] = [
  total_a, total_a * 100 / fixed_vals['Global Total']['Total'][0]
]

fixed_vals['Global Total']['B'] = [
  fixed_vals['Global Total']['Total'][0] - total_a,
  fixed_vals['Global Total']['Total'][0] - fixed_vals['Global Total']['A'][1]
]

for player, vals in fixed_vals.items():
  if player != 'Global Total':
    vals['A'][1] = vals['A'][0] * 100 / fixed_vals['Global Total']['A'][0]
    vals['B'][1] = fixed_vals['Global Total']['A'][1] - vals['B'][1]
```

the problem being that this is not very flexible since I have to do something similar to this,
 but with almost 12 categories (A, B, ...)

Is there a better approach to this? Perhaps this is trivial with pandas?

**Edit for clarification:**

There are no duplicate categories for each Player, everyone of them has the same sequence (some might have 0 but the category is unique)

Comment: what if player1 had 2 entries for A?  are the players always sequenitally increasing? (ie PLAYER1 comes **BEFORE** PLAYER2 in the list of tuples and PLAYER 5 Comes after PLAYER4?) are there always the same 12 categories (`A..L`) ?

Comment: In your desired dict, which of those items are variables, and which are string?  I can't test on your posted code, since you failed to provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune there you go :)

Comment: Your code crashes at `sum(v[1][0] for ...` with a key error on `1`, since there's no such key.

Comment: how is Player1['Total][1] calculated?

Comment: @Prune I am deeply sorry, I believe that should fix it.

Comment: It still fails.  I'm done.  I hope the `groupby` answer solves your problem.

Comment: Please explain how the second items in each list is calculated?

Comment: @pylang The 2nd item is the percentage of that Player related to that category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone seems attracted to a dict-only solution, but why not try converting to `pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd

# given
tuple_list = [('Player1', 'A', 1, 100),
('Player1', 'B', 15, 100),
('Player2', 'A', 7, 100),
('Player2', 'B', 65, 100),
('Global Total', None, 88, 100)]

# make a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(tuple_list , columns = ['player', 'game','score', 'pct'])
del df['pct']
df = df[df.player!='Global Total']
df = df.pivot(index='player', columns='game', values='score')
df.columns.name='' 
df.index.name='' 

# just a check 
assert df.to_dict() == {'A': {'Player1': 1, 'Player2': 7}, 
                        'B': {'Player1': 15, 'Player2': 65}}

#         A   B
#player        
#Player1  1  15
#Player2  7  65
print('Obtained dataset:\n', df)
```

Basically, all you need is 'df' dataframe, and the rest you can 
compute and add later, no need to save it to dictionary.

Below is updated on OP request:

```
# the sum across columns is this - this was the 'Grand Total' in the dicts
#  A     8
#  B    80
sum_col = df.sum(axis=0)

# lets calculate the share of each player score:
shares = df / df.sum(axis=0) * 100
assert shares.transpose().to_dict() == {'Player1': {'A': 12.5, 'B': 18.75}, 
                                        'Player2': {'A': 87.5, 'B': 81.25}}
# in 'shares' the columns add to 100%:
#         A     B
#player             
#Player1 12.50 18.75
#Player2 87.50 81.25

# lets mix up a dataframe close to original dictionary structure 
mixed_df = pd.concat([df.A, shares.A, df.B, shares.B], axis=1)
totals = mixed_df.sum(axis=0)
totals.name = 'Total'
mixed_df = mixed_df.append(totals.transpose())
mixed_df.columns = ['A', 'A_pct', 'B', 'B_pct']    
print('\nProducing some statistics\n', mixed_df)
```

Comment: Do you mind putting the additional steps? I'm failing to achieve the result.

Comment: The steps to get the totals?

Comment: Yes, please. I'm failing to add the column to the rows and have no idea on how to add a percentage column between columns, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to concat the columns dinamically? I'm thinking on adapting this to a dataset with a lot more columns. Something like `pd.concat([df.a, mixed.a, ..., df.t, mixed.t], index=1)`

Comment: Perhaps this, @EvgenyPogrebnyak: `pd.concat([val for sub in zip([df[col] for col in df.columns.values.tolist()], [mixed_df[col] for col in mixed_df.columns.values.tolist()]) for val in sub], axis=1)` ??

Comment: I'd think this: `import itertools;
cols = itertools.chain.from_iterable([(df[a], shares[b]) for a, b in zip(df.columns, 
                                           shares.columns)]) ;
mixed_df = pd.concat(cols, axis=1)`, but maybe theres something nicer /smaller. You'd have to change the new column names too, so probably deserves a separate specific question with first attempts included.

Answer (score 1):

one solution would be to use groupby to group consecutive Player scores from the same player

```
tup = [('Player1', 'A', 1, 100),('Player1', 'B', 15, 100),('Player2', 'A', 7, 100),    ('Player2', 'B', 65, 100),    ('Global Total', None, 88, 100)]`
```

then import our groupby

```
from itertools import groupby

result = dict((name,dict((x[1],x[2:]) for x in values)) for name,values in groupby(tup,lambda x:x[0]))
```

then just go and update all the totals

```
for key in result:
    if key == "Global Total": continue # skip this one ...
    # sum up our player scores
    result[key]['total'] = [sum(col) for col in zip(*result[key].values())]

# you can print the results too
print result

# {'Player2': {'A': (7, 100), 'total': [72, 200], 'B': (65, 100)}, 'Player1': {'A': (1, 100), 'total': [16, 200], 'B': (15, 100)}, 'Global Total': {'total': [88, 100], None: (88, 100)}}
```

**NOTE** This solution **!REQUIRES!** that all of player1's scores are grouped together in your tuple, and all of player2's scores are grouped etc

Comment: The output of this function does not generate proper percentages.

Comment: ahh true .... I misread the problem statement and have no interest in redoing it... ill delete this solution soon

Answer (score 0):

A) Break your code up into manageable chunks:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(dict)
for (cat, sub, num, percent) in input_list:
    result[cat][sub] = [num, percent]
```

Now we have a dict with the player counts, but the only valid percentages are for total and we don't have global counts.

```
from collections import Counter
def build_global(dct):
    keys = Counter()
    for key in dct:
        if key == "Global Total":
            continue
        for sub_key in dct[key]:
            keys[sub_key] += dct[key][sub_key][0]
    for key in keys:
        dct["Global Total"][key] = [keys[key], 100]
```

`build_global(result)` now yields valid global counts for each event.

Finally:

```
def calc_percent(dct):
    totals = dct["Global Total"]
    for key in dct:
        local_total = 0
        if key == "Global Total":
            continue
        for sub_key in dct[key]:
            local_total += dct[key][sub_key][0]
            dct[key][sub_key][1] = (dct[key][sub_key][0]/float(totals[sub_key][0])) * 100
        dct[key]['Total'] = [local_total, (local_total/float(dct['Global Total'][None][0])) * 100]
```

`calc_percent(result)` goes through and builds the percentages.

result is then:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, 
    {'Player2': {'A': [7, 87.5], 'B': [65, 81.25], 'Total': [72, 81.81818181818183]}, 
     'Player1': {'A': [1, 12.5], 'B': [15, 18.75], 'Total': [16, 18.181818181818183]}, 
     'Global Total': {'A': [8, 100], None: [88, 100], 'B': [80, 100]}})
```

If you need it *exactly* as specified, you can delete the `None` entry in global total and `dict(result)` to convert the `defaultdict` into a vanilla `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a remapping tool from [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) in Python 3.6+:

**Given**

```
import copy as cp
import collections as ct

import more_itertools as mit


data = [
    ("Player1", "A", 1, 100),
    ("Player1", "B", 15, 100),
    ("Player2", "A", 7, 100),
    ("Player2", "B", 65, 100),
    ('Global Total', None, 88, 100)
]

# Discard the last entry
data = data[:-1]

# Key functions
kfunc = lambda tup: tup[0]
vfunc = lambda tup: tup[1:]
rfunc = lambda x: {item[0]: [item[1]] for item in x}
```

**Code**

```
# Step 1
remapped = mit.map_reduce(data, kfunc, vfunc, rfunc)

# Step 2
intermediate = ct.defaultdict(list)
for d in remapped.values():
    for k, v in d.items():
        intermediate[k].extend(v)

# Step 3
remapped["Global Total"] = {k: [sum(v)] for k, v in intermediate.items()}
final = cp.deepcopy(remapped)
for name, d in remapped.items():
    for lbl, v in d.items():
        stat = (v[0]/remapped["Global Total"][lbl][0]) * 100
        final[name][lbl].append(stat)
```

---

**Details**

Step 1 - build a new dict of `remapped` groups.

This is done by defining key functions that dictate how to process the keys and values.  The reducing function processes the values into sub-dictionaries.  See also [docs for more details on `more_itertools.map_reduce`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce).

```
>>> remapped
defaultdict(None,
            {'Player1': {'A': [1], 'B': [15]},
             'Player2': {'A': [7], 'B': [65]}})
```

Step 2 - build an `intermediate` dict for lookups

```
>>> intermediate
defaultdict(list, {'A': [1, 7], 'B': [15, 65]})
```

Step 3 - build a `final` dict from the latter dictionaries

```
>>> final
defaultdict(None,
            {'Player1': {'A': [1, 12.5], 'B': [15, 18.75]},
             'Player2': {'A': [7, 87.5], 'B': [65, 81.25]},
             'Global Total': {'A': [8, 100.0], 'B': [80, 100.0]}})
```